# grep giving incorrect results

Tags: python, regex, grep

I have a text file which contains lines having numeric values at the end of line. When I execute the command `cat *.txt | grep 'MOS-LCNB:1.'` I expect values only with `1.`, but for some reason it is showing `100.0`.

```
MOS-LCNB:1.23
MOS-LCNB:1.41
MOS-LCNB:1.83
MOS-LCNB:100.0
MOS-LCNB:1.19
MOS-LCNB:1.39
MOS-LCNB:100.0
MOS-LCNB:100.0
```

Same problem occurs when I write a python script and perform re.search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `.` matches any character except line break.

To match a literal period, you need to precede it with a backslash.

```
grep 'MOS-LCNB:1\.'
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/V9JVHm)

Comment: Future readers may be interested to know you can also match a literal dot with `[.]`. Sometimes it's nice just to avoid [Leaning Toothpick Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

Answer (score 2):

`grep` (and Python `re.search`) are giving correct results. You need to understand Regular Expressions though.

`.` means "any character". To match the period, use `\.`:

```
cat *.txt | grep 'MOS-LCNB:1\.'
```

Comment: You should not use `cat` with programs that can read data itself, like `grep`.  This should do: `grep 'MOS-LCNB:1\.' *.txt`

Comment: @Jotne: a) Yes, that is better. I was merely doing the minimal edit to OP's code so it would work. b) Why "shouldn't"? Sure, it's not as efficient, and I normally use the direct form, but it hardly makes a difference even if you do pipe `cat`. Do you have specific horror tales that result from `cat` use?

Comment: It will for sure work, but for all who reads answers here, it’s always best to do it the best way.  You may lose functionality, like in `awk`s `FILENAME`.  You start more process, more memory, it may take some longer time to execute.